# Google Place Autocomplete status code 9008

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have implemeted the PlaceAutocomplete and it works fine.
but When i generate an apk it doesn't work it shows me the following error:

Error:Status{statusCode=unknown status code 9008,resolution=null}

in my manifest i have added the line :

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="my_api_key" />
```

Comment: you mean to say it works with debug.apk but doesn't works with signed apk, is that correct?

Comment: it works when i run it with the cable connected. when i press generate signed apk it doesn't work ,not in debug apt and not release apk

Comment: Have you generated signed apk for your application..if yes, you might have used keystore file situated in your machine...just create new api key similarly the one you created earlier but this time enter the new sha-1 obtained from .keystore file...Refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you very much !! you are right when i generated the SHA1 i have used the wrong .keystore file.

Comment: Glad i could help! Happy coding!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, you need to enable the Google Places API for Android enable
It's on google api console.

regards